# How to execute more than one query at the same time in mssql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I know ; lets more than one query exicute in studio management but does anyone know how to join these queries together so they run as one. below is a basic query but I would like to run about 5 of these together rather than create different reports for them. they all have different where clauses and have the same amount of columns each. Is there a way of doing this??

Cheers!

```
SELECT     InspectionProcedureName AS Inspection, COUNT(*) AS Total
FROM         UnitData_Vehicle
WHERE     (DATEDIFF(day, InspectionDateTime, GETDATE()) = 1)
GROUP BY InspectionProcedureName
```

I would like to see

```
Inspection  Total
qc             10
Inspection  Total
photo         20
Inspection  Total
insp         30
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [union all](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx) to get one result set from your queries

```
SELECT     InspectionProcedureName AS Inspection, COUNT(*) AS Total
FROM         UnitData_Vehicle
WHERE     (DATEDIFF(day, InspectionDateTime, GETDATE()) = 1)
GROUP BY InspectionProcedureName
UNION ALL
SELECT     InspectionProcedureName AS Inspection, COUNT(*) AS Total
FROM         AnotherTable
WHERE     (DATEDIFF(day, InspectionDateTime, GETDATE()) = 1)
GROUP BY InspectionProcedureName
UNION ALL
-- Next query etc...
```

Comment: ok, that sounds like it but the information is all coming from the same table? is there a way round this?

Comment: @tyrone2011 – That is not a problem. You can use the same table in the different queries.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [UNION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx) operation.